# Azure Bot deployed but not working error as Invalid AppId passed on token

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-bot-service, azure-appservice

I have created Azure App service, Bot Channels Registration, Resource group in Azure Portal and also have a LUIS app created.
I have a custom nodejs code that works perfectly in local using bot emulator.

However, when I upload it to the azure using git it is not working, getting error as "Error: Unauthorized. Invalid AppId passed on token:"  in bot emulator, it is neither working in test in webchat getting error as "There was an error sending this message to your bot"

It seems like Appid and Password used in the code are just fine.
I have taken appid and pwd from configuration of my App service.
Message endpoint taken from settings of my Bot channels Registration

Are there any other things to be created for my BOT to work.

Kindly suggest

Comment: can you double-check the steps you followed for [continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) using GitHub? When you deployed the bot to Azure before enabling continuous deployment, was the bot working as expected in 'Test in Web Chat' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved after clearing the credentials in my systems credential manager :-)